# What does String.iter() do in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am getting confused with some code from Rust but I am managing it. But I have problem in understanding how the function `iter()` work in Rust. What is the possible result for a String?

**Edit**

```
impl Selector {
    pub fn specificity(&self) -> Specificity {
        // http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity
        let Selector::Simple(ref simple) = *self;
        let a = simple.id.iter().len();
        let b = simple.class.len();
        let c = simple.tag_name.iter().len();
        (a, b, c)
    }
}
```

Where `simple.id` is `string`.

Comment: Could you be more precise? The `iter` function (as for all other things) returns something implementing the `Iterator` trait ...

Comment: You should add a code example of what you mean. I don't think there *is* an `iter` on either `&str` or `String` ([code example](http://is.gd/rADesd)).

Comment: @Adham, your example is not complete. FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve; http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: You should also include links to source code that you are referencing. We don't all have implicit knowledge of every piece of software that exists on the Internet! ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be referencing code from [Robinson](https://github.com/mbrubeck/robinson), specifically [this file](https://github.com/mbrubeck/robinson/blob/79a0291b90694397d510dd381af1a80090fbe9c6/src/css.rs).

Note that `SimpleSelector` is defined as:

```
pub struct SimpleSelector {
    pub tag_name: Option<String>,
    pub id: Option<String>,
    pub class: Vec<String>,
}
```

So `id` is *not* a `String`, but an [`Option<String>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html).

[`iter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.iter) on `Option` is defined as:

> Returns an iterator over the possibly contained value.

This allows you to write code that will happen if the value is `Some` and will not happen if it is `None`.

Comment: Thank you friend! I am trying to translate this code into java, how could the iter() be in java language ?

Comment: @Adham that's bigger than will fit in a comment - you should ask a new question for that.

Comment: If you don't mind, please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27461750/how-to-translate-iter-operation-on-optionstring-types-in-rust-into-the-equiv